# Delay or async queries made from Zapier to Salesforce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, salesforce, webhooks, zapier

I have a setup on Zapier that triggers a query to Salesforce each time a user buy tickets from one of my applications. The flow goes as follows:

New user buys a ticket, then a webhook configuration sends the ticket information to Zapier and once zapier's got the data, it triggers a find query to salesforce which tries to find a record with the user's id/passport and if the record doesn't exist, it must then create a new record on SF and map the ticket information to that record & if the record exists already, then the system must just append the ticket information on the record in SF side.

The issue that I have is that if a new user that has no record on SalesForce buys more than one ticket on my application, SF's mapping only the last ticket information after creating the resource and the other tickets abort the SF mapping process yet they are supposed to just append one after the other under the recently created resource, my thinking is that this is happening because the find record query happens in one iteration regardless of the number of tickets purchased by the user, is there possibly a way to do async/delay checks of finding a record on salesforce for each ticket.

Answer (score 0):

So if you need to inject a delay to a zap the easiest thing to do is to use a delay function. Or use a Python code step and run the following to delay the function for a few seconds:

```
import time
sleep(5)
```

However, it sounds more like you might need to use the Zapier Loop function to go through each ticket and append it record. You can read more about it here: https://zapier.com/help/create/other-functions/loop-your-zap-actions

I hope this helps :)